# Deformations when using subdivision surface

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I'm really happy with this model because its simple and low poly, but when i try to use a subdivision surface modifier, some places where i kinda cheated the result, like merging vertices or whatever, the mesh deforms. I can't figure out what's wrong with the mesh.

Below are the before/after pics and a link to the blend file.

[image: before]
[image: after]

[**And the file**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17iiR0ZRSut9G7MX1WgKurmWOQGDjTKO3)

I've tried creating loopcuts and all the clean-up options.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think here are the main problems with your mesh:

- You need to create some edge loops close to the angles if you want them to be sharp.
- You have a lot of inside faces. Select them and delete.
- Try to avoid triangles, use the Knife tool to create quads: <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through the mesh.

[image]